# Ubuntu touch how to get HTML 5 app template running?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-emulator

I have successfully installed the ubuntu sdk on my Ubuntu 14.04LTS, I also have installed a desktop Kit and an UbuntuSDK for i386. Afterwards I created a new html5 app. The template given works with the desktop Kit without any problems.

I also got the emulator to work (Build 5554).
However, when I try to build the template called "untitled1" in my case an error appears.

```
Fatal error: /tmp/untitled1.username_0.1_all.click failed to install.WARNING:root:Signature check failed, but installing anyway as requested
Cannot install /tmp/untitled1.username_0.1_all.click: Framework "ubuntu-core-15.04" not present on system (use --force-missing-framework option to override)
```

You can see my setup options as well as the error raised in the screenshot

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to circumvent this error or how to apply the suggested " --force-missing-framework option " ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two days later I found the answer myself. I kind of made the problem up by myself. But may be the answer will help others.

When creating a new project one is asked for the corresponding framework. I simply used the default value "Ubuntu core 15.04" but I have to change it to 14.04. Now everything works quite well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Felix.
You just saved me 2 days ...

And I found out, that you can change that setting by manipulating the **Framework** setting in the **manifest.json** file in the project directory.